# VBA macro sometimes skipping adding data

Tags: excel, vba

This code takes a line of data from a worksheet and adds it to another worksheet if the data is not present.  The destination workbook is made up of a summary sheet for each day and then a sheet for each agent where the days' data is stored specific to that agent.

It used to run just fine. I pulled data from the source worksheet over and over.  It seemed more efficient to load the data into the daily worksheet, close the source workbook, and use the daily worksheet to supply the data to each agent's worksheet.

If I run it step by step, it works properly, but when I let it run on its own, it skips some data.

```
Sub repDaily(currDate As Date, srcSht As Worksheet, lastRow As Integer)

    Dim destSht As Worksheet, destTemp As String, i As Integer: i = 4
    'set a loop to look at a name and completely process it, then move to the next one
    Do
        destTemp = srcSht.Range("A" & i).Value
        If srcSht.Range("D" & i).Value <> 0 Then
            sheetSearch destTemp, destSht, srcSht
            dataFill destSht, srcSht, lastRow, currDate
            'Application.Wait (Now + 0.0001) 'add a breath to avoid app problems
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i < (lastRow - 1)

End Sub
```

I tried to add a pause after each worksheet is updated, but that has had no effect.  I left the line in just in case it should appear somewhere else in the code.

Ok, I was trying to keep this short for readability, but I can include the 2 functions.  Here they are.

```
Function sheetSearch(destTemp As String, destSht As Worksheet, srcSht As Worksheet)
'this comes from repDaily
'establishes if a worksheet exists and makes it if it doesn't
    
    Dim destWb As Workbook: Set destWb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    For Each sht In destWb.Worksheets
        If sht.Name = destTemp Then
            Set destSht = destWb.Sheets(destTemp)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next sht
    
    'since there was not a worksheet there, make one
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = destTemp
    Set destSht = destWb.Sheets(destTemp)
    
    'adding the column headings
    destSht.Range("A1").Value = "Date"
    destSht.Range("B1").Value = srcSht.Range("C1").Value
    destSht.Range("C1").Value = srcSht.Range("D1").Value
    destSht.Range("D1").Value = srcSht.Range("E1").Value
    destSht.Range("E1").Value = srcSht.Range("F1").Value
    destSht.Range("F1").Value = srcSht.Range("G1").Value
    destSht.Range("G1").Value = srcSht.Range("H1").Value
    destSht.Range("H1").Value = srcSht.Range("I1").Value
    destSht.Range("I1").Value = srcSht.Range("J1").Value
    destSht.Range("J1").Value = srcSht.Range("K1").Value
    destSht.Range("K1").Value = srcSht.Range("L1").Value
    destSht.Range("L1").Value = srcSht.Range("M1").Value

End Function
Function dataFill(destSht As Worksheet, srcSht As Worksheet, lastRow As Integer, _
                    currDate As Date, i As Integer)
'this comes from repDaily
'load data into sheet
    
    'find the last line of the destination sheet
    Dim rowDest As Integer
    rowDest = destSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'search the sheet to find the right place to add the data and insert a line
    Dim dateLine As Date
    Do Until rowDest = 0
        If rowDest = 1 Then   'if there are no entries after the headers, just add one
            rowDest = 2
            Exit Do
        End If
        'rowDest was set to bottom line of sheet.  dateLine is the date for that line.
        'iterate rowDest one line higher at a time until it finds dateLine is smaller than date of the entry
        dateLine = destSht.Cells(rowDest, 1).Value
        If dateLine = currDate Then
            Exit Function
        End If
        If dateLine > currDate Then
            destSht.Cells(rowDest, 1).EntireRow.Insert
            Exit Do
        End If
        If rowDest = 2 Then
            destSht.Cells(rowDest, 1).EntireRow.Insert
            Exit Do
        End If
        rowDest = rowDest - 1
    Loop
    
    'insert data
    destSht.Range("A" & rowDest).Value = currDate
    destSht.Range("B" & rowDest).Value = srcSht.Range("C" & i).Value
    destSht.Range("C" & rowDest).Value = srcSht.Range("D" & i).Value
    destSht.Range("D" & rowDest).Value = srcSht.Range("E" & i).Value
    destSht.Range("E" & rowDest).Value = srcSht.Range("F" & i).Value
    destSht.Range("F" & rowDest).Value = srcSht.Range("G" & i).Value
    destSht.Range("G" & rowDest).Value = srcSht.Range("H" & i).Value
    destSht.Range("H" & rowDest).Value = srcSht.Range("I" & i).Value
    destSht.Range("I" & rowDest).Value = srcSht.Range("J" & i).Value
    destSht.Range("J" & rowDest).Value = srcSht.Range("K" & i).Value
    destSht.Range("K" & rowDest).Value = srcSht.Range("L" & i).Value
    destSht.Range("L" & rowDest).Value = srcSht.Range("M" & i).Value
    
    destSht.Range("A" & rowDest & ":L" & rowDest).Font.Bold = False
    destSht.Range("J" & rowDest & ":L" & rowDest).NumberFormat = "mm:ss"
    destSht.Range("D" & rowDest & ":I" & rowDest).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000005) 'add a breath to avoid app problems
    
    destSht.Columns("A:L").AutoFit
    destSht.Range("A1:L1").Font.Bold = True
    destSht.Range("B" & rowDest & ":L" & rowDest).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    
End Function
```

Comment: This clearly relies on two other subs, `sheetSearch` and `dataFill`. It's probable that the issue is with one of those rather than in the above code.

Comment: It's rare to need to "wait" when doing this type of thing - there are few cases where Excel does things asynchronously (ie. returns control to your code before the thing you asked it to do is complete) As pointed out already, we can't help you with only a snippet of code.

Comment: What is destSht?

Comment: is `destSht` assigned inside sheetSearch ? ie a ByRef parameter

Comment: Another side note, I think you want 'DoEvents' instead of Application.Wait. Application.Wait suspends **All** Excel activity. DoEvents suspends the macro for 1ms to allow other things to happen.

Comment: Makes sense.  I've added the 2 functions.